# Remove console logs from ionic app (release)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

How do I get rid of console logs from an ionic 2 release application?

I am developing an ionic 2 app. When I build the release apk and run on a device, I can still attach to the process from chrome://inspect, and view console logs. I have tried removing the cordova-plugin-console, but that makes no difference.

Edit: I found a package that can remove console logs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/remove-console-logs
Just not sure how I can use it to automatically remove them when I build release. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove "cordova-plugin-console" and then see what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you can still connect with the debugger then it is not a release build  - sounds like you may be unintentionally installing the debug build OR connecting to some other app.

EDIT; Above is not necessarily true - there are instances where you can debug the js/html/css content via chrome in a release build ; specifically if the webview debuggability flag is set in code / not set by the build system etc. - this flag is *seperate from the application debug flags* so if not properly set you will be able to debug a "release" build / not be able to debug a "debug" build - see [remote debugging webviews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews).
END OF EDIT.

( note you have to sign a release build before it will install )

Is it possible the release install failed and you're still looking at a previous debug build ?

Assuming you have a release build and can't connect to see logs via chrome inspect then ;

console.log calls will still be in the release build unless you comment them out - and possibly visible in other ways eg. android tools sdk\tools\monitor - The only way to be sure they aren't visible is to comment them out. You could use something like ;

```
console.log = function(){} ;
```

at the end of your device ready function after any plugins have done anything they're likely to do - though there's still no 100% guarantee with this as a badly behaving 3rd party plugin or library might reassign it later and then your calls will still happen - to be absolutely sure you will need to comment them out.

Comment: I definitely installed the release build. I tried uninstall in the app first and then installed the release apk. I did sign the apk when I built it.

Comment: I will try create a new project and test to confirm 100%

Comment: just uninstall via the application manager in settings on the device, then install directly from the command line with "adb -s <your device id as listed by "adb devices"> install <your release apk file>

Comment: Or if you can build the release , NOT sign it and try installing that - installing an unsigned release build should fail - which would indicate the release apk is actually a debug apk if it does install.

Comment: Uninstalled via app manager. Built unsigned release apk. Couldn't install it. Built signed release apk. Installed fine. Can still attach with chrome://inspect and see console logs. Even more concerning, I can also see unencrypted https traffic requests and responses.

Comment: I'm imagining that the signing and installation of your release apk is all happening as part of the build process (which sounds suspect)  The unsigned release apk that you couldn't install - sign that from the cmd line yourself and try and install it from the cmd line (with adb install) after uninstalling any existing versions on the device.

Comment: Ok. I took the unsigned release apk that wouldn't install, zipaligned and then signed it with jarsigner. Uninstalled the app and then installed the new signed apk using adb install. I can still see the console logs and HTTPS packets.

Comment: I've just amended the answer but I cannot see how you are connecting to a release build via chrome://inspect. As far as I'm aware you should not be able to - (I certainly can't) and it violates android security - console access to a release app gives a user access to your app files. Clutching at straws here but is your device rooted ?

Comment: My device has since stopped working completely.  With both release/debug build, I can't attach anymore.  Not sure what went wrong.  I tried with Genymotion and I have the same result.  I can view console logs and network traffic with chrome://inspect.  I also tried building a new project from the blank template, with the same results: 
`ionic start -v2 testblank blank`
`ionic plugin rm cordova-plugin-console`
`ionic platform add android@6.1.0`
`ionic build android --release --prod -- --keystore="..." --alias=...`
The resulting android-release.apk is 3 489 560 bytes.

Comment: inside \sdk\build-tools\<some version> you'll find aapt. If you run >aapt dump badging <your apk file> you'll get a list which should include "application-debuggable" for a debug build and not include it for a release build.

Maybe try an ionic 1 build instead to see what happens there.

Aside from that there's nothing else I can suggest at this point....

Comment: ...There are really 2 questions here ; the original "how to remove console.log output from a release build" and why an ionic release build for android is accessible via chrome://inspect - at this point someone else should be better able to answer that for you.

For now, I'd suggest you post something like "why is ionic release build for android accessible with chrome://inspect" as a seperate question.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I can confirm that my release build doesn't include application-debuggable, so will ask in a separate thread. I also found a package that may be able to remove the logs if I can get it to work. I will update original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use uglifyjs.config.js for drop all console logs when is a production build.

1 . Copy uglifyjs.config.js from node_modules into your project folder

2 . In the new config file set the flag drop_console to true if production

```
var isProduction = process.env.IONIC_ENV === 'prod'; 

...

compress: {
  drop_console: isProduction
}
```

3 . Set your custom configuration in the package.json

```
"config": { "ionic_uglifyjs": "uglifyjs.config.js" },
```

And that's all !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried remove console logs ?

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

Then

```
cordova build --release android
```

Comment: As per my original post, I have removed the plugin. Only difference is that I build using `ionic build android --release --prod`.